# Use a texture as an influence map without showing any diffuse color

Tags: materials, texturing

I'm trying to use material for color and texture for the appearance (smooth,rough...)

But it assigns me the color of the texture too.
I'm trying to make the gem in here: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/70566
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable the Diffuse *Color* check box under *Influence* in the texture panel (or set it to 0). This prevents the texture from showing any color when rendered.

[image]

Both objects below use the same texture and have the same material colour, the second one also has *Normal* checked as an example of using the texture as a bump map.

[image]